# Compare Multiple Columns VBA EXCEL (Nested Loops)

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code which compares two different sheets at the same time.

```
Dim compareRange As Range
Dim toCompare As Range
Dim rFound As Range
Dim cel As Range

Set compareRange = Worksheets("sheet2").Range("A1:A" & Lastrow3)
Set toCompare = Worksheets("sheet3").Range("A1:A" & Lastrow4)
Set rFound = Nothing

For Each cel In toCompare
    Set rFound = compareRange.Find(cel)
    Z = compareRange.Find(cel).Row
    If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
        cel.EntireRow.Interior.Color = vbGreen
        Set rFound = Nothing
    End If
Next cel
```

However this only compares column A's when I want to compare column A's C'd and D's at the same time and only pass when all three match. The sheets have duplicate values that is why I need to compare 3 items at a time but some columns are identical. I have to use a nested loop. Any idea where to start?

I thought I could do something like

```
Set compareRange = Worksheets("sheet2").Range("A1:A, C1:C, D1:D" & Lastrow3)
```

But apparently I can't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you are not comparing other two columns in your code. Try below code.

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim compareRange As Range, toCompare As Range
    Dim lastRow1 As Long, lastRow2 As Long
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3")
    lastRow1 = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    lastRow2 = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Set compareRange = ws1.Range("A1:A" & lastRow1)
    Set toCompare = ws2.Range("A1:A" & lastRow2)

    For i = 1 To lastRow2
        For j = 1 To lastRow1
            If ws2.Cells(i, 1) = ws1.Cells(j, 1) And ws2.Cells(i, 3) = ws1.Cells(j, 3) And ws2.Cells(i, 4) = ws1.Cells(j, 4) Then
                ws2.Cells(i, 1).Interior.Color = vbGreen
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

Let me know if anything is not clear.

Comment: Im a little confused maybe I messed up but sheet 3 has more values than sheet 2 so I want to compare sheet 3 against sheet 2 and make sure those items exist in sheet3

Comment: @AngatvirSanghera - That really shouldn't be a problem, are you not getting desired result?

Comment: @AngatvirSanghera - Above solution compares each row from `Sheet3` to each row in `Sheet2` and when three columns are same it will highlight that row.

Comment: I'm an idiot yes I am. If I was to make a new row underneath the row once the if loop passed would it mess up the entire loops?

Comment: @AngatvirSanghera - Adding row every time will certainly disturb the loop as number of rows will increase i.e. your data will go down and will not be considered for comparison because last row was calculated with the original data.

Comment: you did not say if all three cells are in the same row. (that is an important piece of information). for this i assume that you want to compare in same row. .... do not compare all three columns at once. ... instead, find two shortest columns. compare cells between these two columns and compare third column only when the first two match.

Comment: @jsotola - I guess `I want to compare column A's C'd and D's at the same time and only pass when all three match` means all three cells in same row.

Comment: Yes they are in the same row but this will only highlight green if all three rows are in the other sheet

Comment: Thanks for your help